# How to create User authentication on Vaadin?

Tags: database, authentication, vaadin

I created a simple login view on Vaadin (using Eclipse IDE) and I created a database on Phpmyadmin. Now how to proceed to verify the username and the password ? Does anyone have some source code examples please ? Thank you so much !

Answer (score 7):

**Here is a handy demo application to get you started...**

Demo:  http://demo.vaadin.com/archetype-application/

Source code : https://github.com/vaadin/archetype-application-example

Accompaning Blog :https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-7-3-7-and-new-maven-archetypes

This has a basic login function but you could expand on this.

**Here is another similar demo...**

Demo : http://dashboard.demo.vaadin.com/#!dashboard

Source code : https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways in doing this.

You can use a solution like [apache shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) which then can authenticate/authorise against different backends.
It has the big advantage that you can (at a later date) switch to another database, a LDAP or ADS backend.

The "simpler" way would be to have a login form, and then validate the username and password via a jdbc query.

The [login form addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/loginform) also has some code ideas for you.